# Dynamic <g:for> in grails

Tags: grails, gsp

I need to display a number of text box in a gsp. The number of text box displayed is picked in a select tag.

I think of something like

```
<g:select name="select" from="${1..10}>

<g:each in="${1..select}">
```

Is there any way I can "pass" the number selected in the select to use it in the for below?

Answer (score 2):

GSP is working on server-side. Value of select tag is available only on client side. 
So, the answer: No, you can't use `<g:each` for selected value.

You have use Javascript instead, like:

```
<g:javascript>
function setupTextboxes() {
  var count = Number($('select[name="select"]').val());
  ........
  put your text boxes into DOM
  ........
}
$(function() {
  $('select[name="select"]').on('change', setupTextboxes)
})
</g:javascript>
```

Comment: Thats what i was doing, but I just was wondering for a I while if there was any piece of grails amgic I was missing. Thank you for you quick answer